# Deriving alternative definition of torsion.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider some curve parametrized by time $t$. For the binormal vector $B$ and unit normal vector $N$ one can show,

$$B'=\frac{dB}{ds}=-\tau N$$

Where $B'$ is the arc length derivative of $B$.

For some $\tau$, let $\tau$ be the called the torsion of the curve. Find an expression of $\tau$ in terms of position vector $r$ (as a function of time) and/or it's time derivatives.

---

My work:

Because $B'$ and $N$ are parallel,

$\text{proj}_{N} B'=B'$

Furthermore from $\text{proj}_{N} B'=(\text{comp}_{N} B') \frac{N}{|N|}$ and $|N|=1$ we get,

$$\tau=-\text{comp}_{N} B'$$

$$=-B' \cdot N$$

Where the above derivative is an arc length derivative. Then running with $B=T \times N$ and the chain rule i.e. $\frac{dB}{ds}=\frac{\frac{dB}{dt}}{\frac{ds}{dt}}$ I get,

$$=-(T \times N') \cdot \frac{N}{|r'|}=-\frac{\text{det}(N,T,N')}{|r'|}$$

Where all derivares above are time derivatives.

Is that even right? If so, now what? I'm stuck.

---

I would like to get eventually to,

$$\tau=\frac{\text{det}(r',r'',r''')}{|r' \times r''|^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Using the chain rule, write what the Frenet equations tell you for a non-arclength parametrized curve. In particular, using prime to denote differentiation with respect to $t$, if you let $\upsilon = \|r'\|$, you'll have
$$T' = \frac{dT}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt} = \kappa\upsilon N.$$
Start with $r' = \upsilon T$.  Differentiate this twice, using the chain rule where appropriate, and inserting the Frenet equations. For example,
$$r'' = \upsilon'T + \upsilon T' = \upsilon' T + \upsilon^2 \frac{dT}{ds} = \dots.$$

Comment: I've made some calculations, I don't see where your hint is going.

Comment: So what do you have for $r''$ and $r'''$?  Note that when you do the determinant, it will be quite simple, because $r'$ involves $T$ only, $r''$ involves $T$ and $N$, and $r'''$ involves $T$, $N$, and $B$.

Comment: I got $r''=v'T+kv^2N$ and $r'''=v'' T+kvv' N+(k' v^2+2kvv')N+kv^2 N'$. Don't see where $B$ is involved.

Comment: Well, what's $N'$?!!

Comment: Oh I see, It is $-kvT+\tau v B$.

Comment: Right. Now finish!! :)

Comment: Ok, thanks! ${}{}{}{}$